# Copy files mentioned in List one by one only after completion

Tags: linux, filesystems, file-transfer, file-management, hadoop

I have a list of file names in a text file `files.txt` which are listed one by one in next line ie.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
file4.txt
...
...
...
```

I have to execute the following command for each of the file.
`hadoop fs -cp /tmp/FILENAME /folder/`

Copy command of next file should initiate only when first operation is over. How can i do it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [`xargs`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html):

```
xargs -a files.txt -i{} hadoop fs -cp /tmp/{} /folder/
```

`xargs` runs commands one by one unless told to run in parallel.